# Is there a single supply voltage implementation of a differential amplifier?

Tags: bjt

So far all implementations I have seen need a positive and negative voltage source. Is there another way like if i supply enough current will it work?

Answer (score 1):

The input stage of the [LM324](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm124-n.pdf) is designed to work from a single supply- input common mode range extends to the negative rail.

[image]

Comment: I think, the question was related to diff. amplifiers only (my understanding). However - independent on this remark - are there opamps which do NOT work with single supply? I dont think so.

Answer (score 0):

A single supply is very common however, to make optimum use of output signal swings, a mid rail dc point is needed. This, for the sake of simplicity, may be shown as 0 volts with positive and negative supply rails.

Comment: I rather think, the output swing capability does not depend on the question single/dual supply. In both cases (+20V or +/-10V or +15/-5 or...) it is possible to select an operationaöl point that allows the same output swing. For my opinion, the most important point is the input resistance (as explained in my detailed answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think, the most important aspect in this regard is the signal input resistance.
Using only one single supply both base nodes must be DC biased with a suitable voltage divider. Of course, the parallel combination of the two resistors influences (reduces) the input resistance which is an undesired effect for diff. amplifiers. In contrary, for two suitable supplies the base potential can be fixed at ground potential (without the need for additional resistors).